# No se actualiza la propiedad @Transient de moneda

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo esta entidad , en la cual he hecho un método PUT y POST , los cuales no dan error pero sin embargo el idMoneda , que es una propiedad calculada con @Transient porque es el ID de la moneda(donde hay una relación 1 a 1 con otra tabla) , no me lo actualiza , cuando miro en la base de datos se me queda a null aunque en la petición POST le meta un valor.
No sé si es porque está mal el setter , o simplemente que hay que añadir algo más que no veo ahora mismo.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REMESA")
public class Remesa {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "remesa_sequence", sequenceName = "remesa_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "remesa_sequence")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "moneda_id", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Moneda moneda;


    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("moneda")
    private Long idMoneda;

    public Long getIdMoneda() {
            return this.moneda.getId();
        }
    
        public void setIdMoneda(Long idMoneda) {
            this.idMoneda = idMoneda;
        }

}
```

En Moneda.java la relación está así:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "moneda", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Remesa remesa;
```

Comment: Si la variable idMoneda es un objeto, ¿por qué no le pones el objeto en vez de long como asignación?

Comment: Así no vale como dices , idMoneda es el id de una moneda por tanto un Long. Además si pruebo a quitarle @Transient , se me añade a la base de datos pero en otra columna , ahora llamada id_moneda , y tendría dos. Id_moneda , moneda_id. Algo está fallando

Comment: Se tendría que insertar automaticamente en moneda_id , pero sin embargo crea otra columna..

Comment: Cuando le pones  "@Transient" a  un dato no se considera como parte del entity que representa la tabla. Lo  que debería funcionarte es hacer de solo lectura tu Relación "@OneToOne". Agregale "@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.Refresh)" y al JoinColumn ponle insertable=false, updatable=false. Con eso la relación es de solo lectura. En el dato IdMoneda quitale el "@Transient" y ponle "@Column(name="moneda_id")". No hay problema que el column name sea igual al JoinColumn. Con lo anterior IdMoneda será tu dato actualizable y moneda tu dato de solo lectura..

Comment: Lo siento , no se me soluciona así. Ahora actualiza bien el POST pero los anteriores registros los elimina con lo que me has dicho @Juan Carlos Guibovich

Comment: He editado la pregunta con la relacion de Moneda.java también. He hecho varios cambios que me has comentado pero no vale porque se eliminan los regtistros anteriores

Comment: Cuales Anterioresr egistros?

Comment: Entonces, mas facil aún, deja todo como estaba y solo cambia los getIdMoneda y setIdMoneda. En el setIdMoneda debes crear el objeto moneda o leerlo de  la tabla Moneda con el IdMoneda. y en el getIdMoneda retorna moneda.moneda_id. IdMoneda dejalo0 en transient.  Solo deberias cambiar el setIdMoneda  para agregarle crear o asignarle valor a campo de la relación moneda.

Comment: No estoy entendiendo , podrías ponerlo en forma de codigo? @JuanCarlosGuibovich

Answer (score 0):

En el  setIdMoneda  deberías  crear  el objeto Moneda. El Entity Moneda debe tener su clase DAO  que permita  obtener las monedas  desde la  base de datos y con ello  haces:

```cpp
   public Long getIdMoneda() {
       return this.moneda.getId();
    }
    
    public void setIdMoneda(Long idMoneda) {
            this.idMoneda = idMoneda;
            this.moneda = daoMoneda.Find(idMoneda);
    }
```

Otra alternativa es que  lo hagas  en el **@PrePersist** del Entity o se la asignas justo  antes  de hacer el *persist*.

Comment: Lo siento pero así no vale , no puedo llamar al dao desde la Entidad ni declarándolo. Incluso con el Autowired al ejecutar da error , no le veo mucho sentido a la respuesta de todas maneras..Pero te lo agradezco

Comment: Hazlo  antes  del  _persist_.

Comment: Sigo sin entenderte , no uso ninguna directiva que se llame "persist"

Comment: En  algún lado debes hacer el  save(remesa). Justo antes  de eso  le das  valor a __moneda__ utilizando  el  IdMoneda.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar